# How to sort array in this way(if it contains A B then it will come first then after that order that query give result)

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
      require 'connection.php';
      $sql1="SELECT m.allocationID,mt.CatId,mt.CatSName FROM msttransaction 
      m,msttemp mt WHERE m.isPending='Y' AND m.allocationID IN ( SELECT 
      mt.AllocationId FROM msttemp WHERE mt.quarterId='020500001') order by 
      SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)";
      $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
      $rows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
      for ($i = 0; $i<$rows; $i++) 
      {
          $result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
          $a=$result['allocationID'];
          $b=$result['CatId'];
          $c=$result['CatSName'];
          echo $a.'  '.$b.'  '.$c."<br>";
      }
?>
```

Output:

```
12980013420170919125529 4 D
12980013720170919125816 1 A
12980013820170919130050 2 B
12980013920170919130209 3 C
12980014020170919130434 4 D
12980014120170920140935 1 A
```

> Note:-129800 series having last 14 digits date and time

I want to arrange this array as

```
12980013720170919125816 1 A
12980014120170920140935 1 A
12980013820170919130050 2 B
12980013420170919125529 4 D
12980013920170919130209 3 C
12980014020170919130434 4 D
```

so every time if array contains A and B it sorts first(A first then B)then other elements remains in same order(or I can say according to date and time)..

Comment: you can use case in sql like `CASE WHEN CatSName = 'A' then 1 WHEN CatSName = 'B' then 2 END as ord` and order by ord, if you need i can write a fully answer

Comment: why can't use order by CatId and CatSName ?

Comment: oO actually just order by like `ORDER BY CatSName, CatId` like user1844933 said will surely works too

Comment: i want only A and B first two place then i want my result according to allocationID that means after A and B it will sort according to AllocationID

Comment: then my comment will work if you add `ELSE 0` in the CASE and `ORDER BY ord, AllocationID`

Comment: if i sort it by CatSName or CatId then it will not give output as i want..i want my remaining order will be according to allocationID last 14 digits which is date and time so which one is first in date and time will come first after A and B hope you understand..MacBooc if you will post full code i am thankful to you

Comment: ok i'll write an answer

Comment: thanks i am waiting.actually i stuck in this code since tomorrow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you have to define the `CASE` statement if i understood what you meant like:

```
$sql1="SELECT 
           m.allocationID,
           mt.CatId,
           mt.CatSName,
           CASE 
               WHEN mt.CatSName = 'A' THEN 0
               WHEN mt.CatSName = 'B' THEN 1
               ELSE 2
           END CASE as ord
       FROM 
           msttransaction m,
           msttemp mt 
       WHERE 
           m.isPending='Y' AND m.allocationID 
       IN ( SELECT 
                mt.AllocationId 
            FROM 
                msttemp 
            WHERE 
                mt.quarterId='020500001') 
        ORDER BY
            ord,
            CatId,
            SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14)";
```

also use joint would be better in performance term than call tow table in the `FROM` statement

Comment: thanks a lot MacBooc.its working i tested for two three conditon its work...thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use this function to directly sort the $result array as you want. You can 
//sort array by any key name to asc or desc. It really works.
//$array = $result
//$value = A value which you want to sort such as product name etc.
//$asc = true or false

    function sortBySubValue($array, $value, $asc = true, $preserveKeys = false)
    {
        if ($preserveKeys) {
        $c = array();
        if (is_object(reset($array))) {
            foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
                $b[$k] = strtolower($v->$value);
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
                $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$value]);
            }
        }
        $asc ? asort($b) : arsort($b);
        foreach ($b as $k => $v) {
            $c[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
        $array = $c;
    } else {
        if (is_object(reset($array))) {
            usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($value, $asc) {
                return $a->{$value} == $b->{$value} ? 0 : ($a->{$value} - $b->{$value}) * ($asc ? 1 : -1);
            });
        } else {
            usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($value, $asc) {
                return $a[$value] == $b[$value] ? 0 : ($a[$value] - $b[$value]) * ($asc ? 1 : -1);
            });
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: 20 lines instead of 2 in sql is worth to you ?

Comment: MacBooc but it gives me the same order       
12980013420170919125529  4   D   2

12980013720170919125816  1   A   0

12980013820170919130050  2   B   1

12980013920170919130209  3   C   2

12980014020170919130434  4   D   2

Comment: @MacBooc its a choice, sometimes we need to use these functions as well as i used it in complex projects. So if its easily done using sql then its the best thing.

Comment: @VAIBHAVRAWAT maybe you are doing anything wrong. Because i have tested and used many times and its perfect for sorting of array.